# Making a colorbar's frame white while keeping the labels black

Tags: matlab, border, customization, matlab-figure, colorbar

How can I make the rectangular line around the box of the colorbar white, but keep the tick labels black?

Reproducible code below:

```
colormap(flipud(autumn(6))); % Create Colormap
         cb = colorbar; % Create Colorbar         
         cb.Ticks = [.1667 .3334 .5001 .6668 .8335]; % Create ticks
         cb.TickLabels = ({'0%','5%','10%','15%','20%'});    
         cb.TickLength = 0;
         cb.Color = 'w'; % Everything becomes white, I only want the rectangular color of the box to be white
```

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo, I modify the question to make it more clear

Comment: Please mention your MATLAB version. Also, are you using figures or uifigures?

Answer (score 3):

You could get the wanted visual effect by overlaying a white annotation box on the colorbar, e.g.

```
    colormap(flipud(autumn(6))); % Create Colormap
             cb = colorbar; % Create Colorbar         
             cb.Ticks = [.1667 .3334 .5001 .6668 .8335]; % Create ticks
             cb.TickLabels = ({'0%','5%','10%','15%','20%'});    
             cb.TickLength = 0;
             % cb.Color = 'w'; % Everything becomes white, I only want the rectangular color of the box to be white

    annotation('rectangle',cb.Position,'Color','w','FaceColor','none','LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @wwweagle, it is a nice workaround that produces the desired effect.

Comment: Does this remain in the right place if the figure is resized after adding the annotation? If not, I would add that this needs to be performed after any resizing.

Comment: @Dev-iL Your solution is clearly better (and upvoted), where did you learn these undocumented features though :) ?

Comment: @wwweagle Really, I think your solution is perfectly valid and would simply benefit from a small clarification. Thanks for the vote! I learned  initially by reading the UndocumentedMATLAB blog, and later by trial and error (the `struct` function is your best friend when digging). After many similar examples I realized that there is always a reference to some "primitive" object such as a line or a patch whose properties or methods one needs to access to succeed. Feel free to stop by [the MATLAB chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/) if you want to discuss such matters further.

Answer (score 3):

From the [ColorBar properties documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html#d122e183732) we learn that the `Color` property changes too many things:

> `Color` — Color of tick marks, text, and box outline

So we have to try something else. Fortunately, if you are comfortable with using an undocumented feature, the desired effect can be achieved by modifying the colorbar's `Ruler` property:

```
function [] = q66408322()
hF = figure();
hAx = axes(hF);
colormap(hAx, flipud(autumn(6)));
hCb = colorbar(hAx,...
  'Ticks', [.1667 .3334 .5001 .6668 .8335],...   
  'TickLabels', {'0%','5%','10%','15%','20%'}, ...
  'TickLength', 0, ...
  'Color', 'w');
hCb.Ruler.Color = 'k'; % <<<<<< Solution
```

Resulting in:

[image]